# How get the status of a server without download the page content in IOS

Tags: ios, connection, response, http-status-codes

I want to check if a web ressource is available without download any data. For exemple, if I do a NSURLConnection on a webPage, I can get the status code:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
   NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
   int code = [httpResponse statusCode];//200 is ok
}
```

But all page datas are downloaded.

How can I get this code (or equivalent) without download this page ?

Comment: To get only the status code, use a `HEAD` request instead of `GET` in your `NSURLConnection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status code comes along with the server answer, once you get the status code you will have the body as well.

Another option is maybe to check if the resource is reachable using the Reachability classes.

Check this [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), it may help.

Update: borrrden pointed in the right direction here (use HEAD method instead of GET) check the comment on your anwser

Comment: This class respond that the host is reachable, however the server is down.

Comment: Check the comment from borrrden. Using the HEAD method is the way to go here.